# конкатенация вывода

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
function setPageThread (name, options = {}) {
    let popular = options.popular;
    let expires = options.expires;
    let activeClass = options.activeClass;
    console.log(name, + " " +,   popular, + " " +, expires, + " " +, activeClass);
    // ....
}
```

я передаю ей параметры:

```
setPageThread("New version out soon!", {
    popular: true,
    expires: 1000,
    activeClass: "is-page-thread"
});
```

и получаю синтаксическую ошибку:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Если убираю пробелы, всё работает:

```
console.log(name,  popular, expires, activeClass);
```

Никак не могу понять, как мне добавить разделитель, пробел или знак `:`. Всё же правильно делаю: пишу `+ ' ' +`, но почему-то не работает.

Comment: `console.log(name + ", " +   popular + ", " + expires + ", " + activeClass);`

Comment: Раз есть `let`, может быть и destructuring — `let {popular, expires, activeClass} = options;`. Или даже `function (name, {popular, expires, activeClass}) { … }`.

Comment: @elmigranto, и как это относится к вопросу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неправильно работаете с консолью, пытаясь использовать конкатенацию там, где она не нужна. Метод [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log) поддерживает так называемые плейсхолхдеры, позволяющие сделать код более наглядным:

```
console.log('%s, %s, %s, %s', name, popular, expires, activeClass);
```

Для такой простой строки это, возможно, избыточное решение, однако оно позволит выработать правильную привычку.

А еще можно использовать специальный синтаксис "шаблонов" ES6, чтобы не заниматься конкатенацией строк вручную:

```
console.log(`${name}, ${popular}, ${expires}, ${activeClass}`);
```

Такие "шаблоны" работают не только в консоли, но и в любых других местах, где ожидается строка.

Comment: только такие шаблоны не во всех браузерах еще пока :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, потому я и указал, что это ES6-фича. При желании, можно использовать транспилятор, вроде Babel. А еще ТС использует в вопросе `let`, поэтому код, скорее всего, уже ориентирован на новые браузеры ;)

Answer (score 2):

А запятые у тебя не там стоят. они в скобках должны быть

Comment: ты бы проверил потом написал, в скобках они тоже не работают, я пробовал

Answer (score 2):

[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log) может принимать несколько параметров.

В данном случае запятыми разделяются параметры функции, и при разборе переданных выражений происходит ошибка в месте где после `+` стоит `,`, о чем, собственно, и говорит текст ошибки.

Для исправления, нужно либо убрать знаки `+`

```
console.log(name, " ",   popular, " ", expires, " ", activeClass);
```

либо убрать запятые

```
console.log(name + " " + popular + " " + expires + " " + activeClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибся при формировании аргумента для `console.log`. Оно и понятно, выглядит запутанно, и печатать неудобно. Чтобы программисту было жить хорошо, все нормальные браузеры пробелы ставят сами — просто передавай, что нужно вывести в консоль:

```
console.log(name, popular, expires, activeClass);
```

Если есть возможность использовать ES6, я предпочитаю такой вариант:

```
console.log({name, popular, expires, activeClass});
```